# How to best iterate through a list within a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
a = {'name': 'Test', 'lastName': 'Test', 'scores': ['1', '2'], 'subjects': ['te','re'] }
```

I have tried nested loops, but I'm not sure if that's the best approach.

As an output I need a list of dictionaries for each score and subject :

```py
result1 = { 'name':'Test', 'lastName': 'Test', 'score': '1', 'subjects': 'te'}
result2 = { 'name':'Test', 'lastName': 'Test', 'score': '2', 'subjects': 're'}
```

How to best iterate through the lists and create such dictionary? The number of scores and subjects will always match.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show what you tried?

Comment: `result1` and `result2` in your example output are exactly the same. I assume the second one was supposed to have `'score': '2', 'subjects': 're'`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function which *unzip* your dictionary.

We first use `next` to find some list value in the dictionary, its length is the expected output size.

Note that this will fail if the dictionary contains no list at all.

```
def unzip_dict(d):
    # Find one of the list in the dictionary to read its length
    length = len(next(value for value in d.values() if isinstance(value, list)))

    output = []

    # Unzip the dictionary
    for i in range(length):
        output.append({k: v[i] if isinstance(v, list) else v for k, v in d.items()})

    return output


a = {'name': 'Test', 'lastName': 'Test', 'scores': ['1', '2'], 'subjects': ['te', 're']}

print(unzip_dict(a))
```

### Output

```
[{'lastName': 'Test', 'name': 'Test', 'scores': '1', 'subjects': 'te'},
 {'lastName': 'Test', 'name': 'Test', 'scores': '2', 'subjects': 're'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# setup data
a = {'name': 'Test', 'lastName': 'Test', 'scores': ['1', '2'], 'subjects': ['te','re'] }

# create list of dictionary
out_list = []
for value in a.get('scores'):
    for item in a.get('subjects'):
        out_list.append({'name': 'Test', 'lastName': 'Test', 'scores':value, 'subjects':item})
```

Output:

```
{'name': 'Test', 'lastName': 'Test', 'scores': '1', 'subjects': 'te'}
{'name': 'Test', 'lastName': 'Test', 'scores': '1', 'subjects': 're'}
{'name': 'Test', 'lastName': 'Test', 'scores': '2', 'subjects': 'te'}
{'name': 'Test', 'lastName': 'Test', 'scores': '2', 'subjects': 're'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need nested for loops, a single for loop is sufficient:

```
def foo(a):
finarr=[]
for i in range(len(a['scores'])):
    fnarr={}
    fnarr['name']=a['name']
    fnarr['lastName']=a['lastName']
    fnarr['score']=a['scores'][i]
    fnarr['subject']=a['subjects'][i]
    finarr.append(fnarr)
return finarr
```

**Output:**

```
[{'name': 'Test', 'lastName': 'Test', 'score': '1', 'subject': 'te'},
{'name': 'Test', 'lastName': 'Test', 'score': '2', 'subject': 're'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this: 
      res1 = {}
       res2= {}

```
for k,v in a.items():
  if(k == "scores"):
    res1[k] = v[0]
    res2[k] = v[1]
  elif(k=="subjects"):
    res1[k] = v[0]
    res2[k] = v[1]
  else:
    res1[k] = v
    res2[k] = v

 print(res1)
 print(res2)
```

you can also take a look to defaultdict i think that would help you on your Task

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize `zip` to attach scores and subjects to each other and then add it to a new list.

```py
d = {'name': 'Test', 'lastName': 'Test', 'scores': ['1', '2'], 'subjects': ['te','re'] }
template = {'name': d['name'], 'lastName': d['lastName']}

res = []
for subject, score in zip(d['subjects'], d['scores']):
    template.update({'subjects': subject, 'scores': score})
    res.append(template)

print(res)
```